# Photo-books with lay-flat pages

Tags: photobooks, printed-album

I am looking for a company that does lay-flat photo-books in large sizes and large number of pages.

Answer (score 2):

While these are by no means the *only* companies who have lay-flat photobooks, they are some of the best-known, most-reputable companies who produce them:

- **Marathon Press** - http://www.marathonpress.com/ - Offset Printer specializing in professional photography products
- **Bay Photo** - http://www.bayphoto.com/ - Genreal high-end photo and photo-product production lab
- **White House Custom Color** - http://www.whcc.com/ - Genreal high-end photo and photo-product production lab
- **Leather Craftsman** - http://leathercraftsmen.net/joomla1/ - High-end album manufacturer
- **Asuka Book** - http://asukabook.com/ - High-end album manufacturer

Obviously each company will have its own specific product lines, prices, policies, etc., so you'll need to contact them for further details specific to your situation. While I do have business relationships with each of these companies, I don't get anything for mentioning them... I'm just an 'average' customer who likes what each of these companies has to offer...

Comment: Thanks! I've already checked out all of those, and none of them meet all my requirements except Asuka. They have great lay-flat albums, but they cost a bit more than I want to spend. This is for personal, not for professional use, so I am looking for something not quite as expensive. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't. You're right that they're quite expensive... I kinda doubt that you're going to find something that's *significantly* less money than what you'll find with these providers...